# SupportMapFragment overriding setOnMyLocationChangeListener

Tags: android, supportmapfragment

I'm trying to override setOnMyLocationChangeListener on a SupportMapFragment using this

```
map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                        LatLng you = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                        float distanceTo = location.distanceTo(venueLocation);
                        String miles = metersToMiles(distanceTo);
                        dist.setText(miles + " miles away");
                        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                        map.clear();
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(venue)
                                .title(centerName)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                        .fromResource(R.drawable.fu_map_marker)));
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .title("You are here")
                                .position(you));
                        builder.include(venue);
                        builder.include(you);
                        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 75));
                    }
                });
```

Which kind of works, however, before the camera animates using the LatLngBounds, it automatically zooms to the users location and adds a blue dot. Is there anyway I can disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing that because you have the My Location layer enabled. You can disabled it by

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
```

Also listening for Location changes that way is deprecated. There is a new [Location api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/location) with the latest version of Google Play services that is supposed to provide the same functionality with less battery usage.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setMyLocationEnabled%28boolean%29